# Is storing Firebase user uid in session storage a vulnerability ? In javascript on client browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, security, browser

Is storing Firebase user Uid in session storage a vulnerability ? In javascript on client browser
after the user is logged in i use the user Uid to get data from firebase database

If this is a vulnerability what better way's can be used to identify user and get user's data from the database

storing data in storage after login:

```
handleLogin = async (evt) => {
   evt.preventDefault();
   await fire
     .auth()
     .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.userName, this.state.password)
     .then((u) => {
       this.props.toggleLogin();
       db.collection('login')
         .where('loginId', '==', u.user.uid)
         .get()
         .then((res) => {

           sessionStorage.setItem('loginId', u.user.uid);
         });
       this.props.history.push('/portfolio');
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
       if (this.state.email === '') {
         this.dialog.showAlert('Please enter a valid email');
       } else if (this.state.password === '') {
         this.dialog.showAlert('Please enter a valid password');
       }
     });
 };
```

get UserId

```
 let data = sessionStorage.getItem('loginId');
```

Answer (score 1):

In any case, any storage in the browser is not safe. You can refer to `vuex` of `VUE` for data storage. You should avoid these problems at the server side. Users can open the console to view API requests and forge them, so the front-end security is really not good